# Check if PostgreSQL table exists with Npgsql

Tags: .net, npgsql

Until now I don't see any difference in using Npgsql driver instead of ODBC when working with PostgreSQL database on windows. But now I find one.

I have such code to check if table exists with ODBC:

```
Public Function dbTableExists(ByVal dbTable As String, ByVal dbName As String) As Boolean

    Dim retval As Boolean = False
    Dim nCon As New OdbcConnection
    Dim btCommand As OdbcCommand = Nothing
    nCon.ConnectionString = "Dsn=" + dbDsn + _
                            ";database=" + dbName & _
                            ";server=" + dbServer + _
                            ";port=" + dbPort + _
                            ";uid=" + dbUser + _
                            ";pwd=" + dbPass
    Try
        nCon.Open()
        btCommand = New OdbcCommand("SELECT 1 FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename='" & dbTable + "'", nCon)
        retval = CBool(btCommand.ExecuteNonQuery())

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        retval = False
    End Try

    Return retval
End Function
```

With this code I get True if specific table exists in determined database or False otherwise.
When I try to use Npgsql instead of ODBC function is very similar:

```
Public Function tExists(ByVal dbTable As String, ByVal dbName As String) As Boolean

    Dim retval As Boolean = False
    Dim btCommand As NpgsqlCommand = Nothing
    Dim nCon As New NpgsqlConnection(String.Format( _
                    "Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};", _
                    dbServer, dbPort, dbUser, dbPass, dbName))
    Try
        nCon.Open()
        btCommand = New NpgsqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename='" & dbTable + "'", nCon)
        retval = CBool(btCommand.ExecuteNonQuery())

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        retval = False
    End Try

    Return retval
End Function
```

But this won't work as expected.
I always get True as result no matter if specific table is present or not.

Any idea how to get Npgsql function to work?

Comment: Why do you use `executeNonQuery()`? You **are** running a query, so shouldn't you be using `executeQuery()` (or something similar - I don't know .Net)

Comment: Hello "name". Your logic is excellent as usually. For some reason MS ODBC return's a value of query with executeNonQuery but Npgsql unexpectedly don't. I didn't know for that difference till now. But here is ExecuteScalar which return first row or value of a (such kind of) query. And such, with ExecuteScalar I get expected result of showed query and get my Npgsql function to work. Thank you for pointing me to right direction.

Comment: Could you include that as an example?  I would be happy to upvote.

Comment: did the method with information_schema work?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you don't want/can't change your query but I suggest you to use the `information_schema` table instead of using `pg_tables`. I personally use this method:

```
 public override bool TableExists(string tableName)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = '" + tableName + "'";
        using (var con = new NpgsqlConnection(preparedConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql))
            {
                if (cmd.Connection == null)
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    cmd.Connection.Open();

                lock (cmd)
                {
                    using (NpgsqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (rdr != null && rdr.HasRows)
                                return true;
                            return false;
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

(Don't care about injection or similar)